# How many-body density $n(\vec{r},t)$ can be viewed as a kind of correlation function?

Tags: many-body, greens-functions, correlation-functions

I am reading Martin's book: [interacting electrons](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/interacting-electrons/4317C43D0531C900920E83DD4632CFE9?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=21c9b04c062e5b54029665b9e12759276eda7052-1578730454-0-AalIYNZ4AHfc8fVnKxL6bCku6h3RQB89wkx_Yj_o_eQD0esW7Bt1AbYECB8Vy2OgOAix959aKYJxXBLk3sZUEopXoaZSXdaz8nafGGqNvgxNeUBANn1LWIlHt_neEBpUALPwoNdGmwEIr_F9jG_UTXqOeQhyYOZ0-20fr-4vsC-yasw_iXGI1DkzKLpp5dyY_4-huzsOAFjwaf5zXfFK9SvtOAIL6y7sD6siS2u7-b8kApeLAHI8cPHHP6VN28J2VmXir-Vzdc38XZ2rku-4o-EIU5u3VMOtbcJ6cb4nsHYC3ULnvWRxHDEzmnZOza3oBWK_eCbXUkQuCGpIF7Qs89RUti7ULO5h11tIGk77azQY8mRC3H3fVxWzvtS2AyHMwrgAztbsuVDgWAy5wejdBBXvwrX12N8Na8hZrzKkO_iz). In chapter five about the definition of the correlation function, some points about density as correlation function confused me.

The author adopted the following definition for the correlation function:

**By definition, a correlation function links at least two quantities. ... Both dynamical and static correlation functions can be written:**

$$C_{AB}(1,2)=\sum_\alpha \omega_\alpha \langle \alpha|\hat{A}_H(1)\hat{B}_{H}(2)|\alpha\rangle \equiv \langle \hat{A}_H(1)\hat{B}_H(2)\rangle.$$

in which the author has defined the operator representing physical quantities in the Heisenberg picture.

The author say also:

**The electron density $n(\vec{r},t)$, a one-body quantity, can be thought of as a correlation function of the position of the electrons at a given time with respect to a fixed reference frame, typically determined by the nuclei, external fields such as due to the walls of the container, or the center of mass of a molecule.**

As you can see, there is a controversy between these statements. How can I understand the viewpoint of density as a correlation function?

Comment: I do not see what the controversy is. Isn't $n(r,t)$ just $\langle c_i(t)^\dagger c_j(t) \rangle$, where $r = r_i =r_j$? So the density is the equal-time correlation function of creating a particle at $r_i$ and annihilating it at the same point.

Comment: If one thinks $n(\vec{r},t)=\langle \hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{r},t)\hat{\psi}(\vec{r},t)\rangle$, then there is no controversy. I agree your comments.